# Property of Standard Normal

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I'm interested in showing that the following relationship holds:

\begin{equation}
X+\frac{\phi(X)}{\Phi(X)} \leq \frac{\Phi(X)}{\phi(X)}  \ \forall X
\end{equation}

Where $\phi$ is the pdf of a a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ is the Cdf of a a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try $X=0$?

Comment: Sorry, should be weak relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to

$$ x \phi(x)\Phi(x)+\phi(x)^2 \leq \Phi(x)^2 \tag{1}$$
or to:

$$ \iint_{(-\infty,x)^2}e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,da\,db \geq x e^{-x^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}\,da + e^{-x^2}\tag{2}$$
or to:
$$ \iint_{(-\infty,x)^2} b^2 e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,da\,db \geq \iint_{(-\infty,x)^2} ab e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,da\,db \tag{3} $$
or (by symmetry of the LHS) to:
$$ \iint_{(-\infty,x)^2} \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,da\,db \geq \iint_{(-\infty,x)^2} ab e^{-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,da\,db \tag{4} $$
that is trivial since $(a^2+b^2)-2ab = (a-b)^2\geq 0$.