# Prove $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(a-\gamma)\sin^2\theta+1}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}}d\theta\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}}d\theta>1$

Tags: elliptic-integrals

How to prove that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(a-\gamma)\cdot\sin^2\theta+1}{\sqrt{1+a\cdot \sin^2\theta}}d\theta\cdot\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1+a\cdot\sin^2\theta}}d\theta>1,\quad \forall a>0,$$
where $\gamma = 2-\frac{16}{\pi^2}$? Any ideas on how to prove this inequality? I found that the LHS is first increasing and then decreasing, and equality holds when $a=0$ and $a\to\infty$. But differentiating might not be a good idea.

Comment: With given value of $\gamma$, you can show that the numerator of the left-hand integrand is always positive. This is also the case for its denominator; and the numerator and denominator of the right-hand integrand. Integrating positive functions yields a positive result, so you know that the "LHS>0". Maybe you can find a similar reasoning to prove "LHS>1".

Comment: You can rewrite the LHS as $\left(a-\gamma\right)\left(I+{\pi\over2}\right)I$, with $I=\int\limits_0^{\pi\over 2}\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}}$, so the remaining question is how to calculate the integral $I$.

Comment: I think you derivation is incorrect...

Comment: Numerically, I do not see where is the problem. For sure, if you exclude differentiation, I suppose that the problem could be difficult.

Comment: @Karlo. This is "quite simple" elliptic integral.

Comment: I want to find a proof of it, not numerical evaluation. I didn't exclude differentiation, but I thought the derivative could be quite nasty...

Comment: It might be a good thing to have a bit of context. That essentially is an inequality for the derivative of a complete elliptic integral of the second kind, so I guess it can be proved through differential equations as usual (have a look at pages 134 and 137 here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio The problem originates from my research. I work in Electronic Engineering. The elliptical integrals are results of taking expectations over functions of certain bivariate Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Well, to know which random variables are considered might be useful. Maybe the given inequality can be proved in a geometric fashion, like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337419/property-of-standard-normal/2337468#2337468

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I guess it is difficult to have some geometric interpretation for my problem. My original problem is kind of difficult to explain in a few sentences, and the inequality above is a small part of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The following inequalities can be proved through the techniques outlined in [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) (pages 134-137), i.e. by exploiting strong convexity and second-order differential equations: $$\forall a>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{4+3a}}$$
$$\forall a>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta =\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{a+1})}\geq \frac{\pi}{1+\sqrt{a+1}}$$

They are enough to prove the claim in a right neighbourhood of the origin, which is a good starting point, at the very least.

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks a lot for the reply. I'm out now and will check your answer tomorrow. I'm wondering if it's possible to reach you via email?

Comment: @junjiema2: you can, but what is the purpose of doing that? Can't you just comment here?

Comment: I looked through your note, but still have no idea on how you derived the first inequality. Could you please provide more details? Thanks you very much.  @Jack D'Aurizio